# Python: Run a function for all objects in a class

Tags: python, function, class

So, I am working with classes and I want to be able to make a class without being forced to call functions for each individual object. Is there any way that I would be able to make 1 or 2 lines of code that run a function for every single object in that class?

Comment: Please clarify your question more, for example I suggest adding a toy example

Comment: You are going to have to clarify what you mean. What do you mean by "run a function for every single object in that class"? What do you mean *objects in a class*, exactly?